# Shabbat Erev Pesach - Piyyutim for Shabbat HaGadol

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, minhag, passover, yotzrot

Ashkenazi custom is (was?) to recite *piyyutim* during *shacharit* of *shabbat hagadol* (the *shabbat* before *pesach*).

As part of the *kerovot*, the *piyyut* [*elo-hei haruchot lechol basar*](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Siddur_Sefard%2C_Yotzerot%2C_Shabbat_HaGadol.43?lang=bi) is recited, containing a digest of the laws of *bedikat chametz*, *hagalat kelim* and *afiyyat hamatzot* (followed by the laws of the *seder*).

What is the custom in a year when *shabbat hagadol* is on *erev pesach*, meaning that one should have already carried out these activities before *shabbat hagadol* started?

Do we simply recite this *piyyut* as normal, notwithstanding its inapplicability? Or maybe we should recite it on the *shabbat* a week earlier, to allow people to put it into practice? Or maybe just skip it altogether in such a year?

If the answer is either of the latter two options, what about the rest of the *piyyutim* for *shabbat hagadol*? Would they follow the same practice as that of *elo-hei haruchot lechol basar* (either being recited a week early or just skipped), or would they be recited in their usual spot, simply omitting *elo-hei haruchot lechol basar*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Rabbi Yehuda Spitz](https://ohr.edu/this_week/insights_into_halacha/) of Ohr Somayach, [there is a four way dispute](https://ohr.edu/9301#_edn2) how to go about things in a year like 5781, where Erev Pesach is on Shabbos.

1. Some say the traditional *Yotzros* as normal (Pri Megadim 430:1, Mishbetzos Zavav 1).
2. Some say it the week before, as the *Yotzros* discuss *bedikas chametz*, which happened on the 13th instead of the 14th (Maharil).
3. A variation of this is to say the second half of the *piyut*, starting with *Yayin Ki*, as it's still relevant.
4. Some don't say it at all this year, keeping in mind the concern of having an abridged prayer service when people have to finish their *chametz* soon afterwards (Luach Eretz Yisroel from [Rav Tucazinsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Michel_Tucazinsky); see Mishnah Berurah (444:4)).

He cited [Piskei Teshuvos (430:2)](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=164303&pagenum=32) for an extensive treatment of these various *minhagim*. See there for more sources.